# Is it possible to horizontally center generated content?

Tags: css

I would like to use CSS to change the appearance of the `<hr>` elements on a page: instead of a horizontal line, I'd like each one to appear as a set of three asterisks. I can accomplish that using something like this:

```
hr {
    border: none;
    margin: 3.0rem auto;
    width: 5rem;
}

hr:before {
    content: "***";
    letter-spacing: 1rem;
}
```

([Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rMNSJ/).)

The problem is getting this generated content to appear horizontally centered. I can get it more-or-less centered by tweaking the "width" property of the `<hr>`, but this feels hacky and inflexible. Is there a way to tell the browser that this content should be centered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this,

```
hr {
    border: none;
    margin: 2.0rem auto;
    text-align:center;
}

hr:before {
    content: "***";
    letter-spacing: 1rem;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rMNSJ/2/

Answer (score 3):

Remove the width property and add `text-align:center;` to the hr rule:

```css
hr {
    border: none;
    margin: 2.0rem auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rMNSJ/3/)**

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/rMNSJ/5/) indicates nicely **a)** _that_ that is still not centered, and **b)** _why_ that is still not centered

Comment: @Eric - the `text-align` property doesn't have anything to do with what you're pointing out. That would be a problem due to the `letter-spacing` property.

Comment: @Eric The problem you mention can be mitigated by setting the `padding-left` of the generated content equal to the `letter-spacing`.